# Cassandra - unable to connect via cqlsh

Tags: bash, cassandra, cqlsh

I have a problem in connecting to cassandra via clqsh. I've deployed a cluster consisting of 3 nodes on CentOS7. I could see that nodes are connecting with each other. nodetool status output is bellow:

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)        Host ID     Rack
UN  ${SEED2} 226.47 KiB     1            60,3%                 <hash>     rack1
UN  ${SEED}  190.77 KiB     1            50,9%                 <hash>     rack1
UN  ${IP}    157.62 KiB     1            88,7%                 <hash>    rack1
```

But connecting via cqlsh doesn't work. I've tried connection to localhost and to node IP. Here is the output of cqlsh command:

```
[root@node02 default.conf]# cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': 
error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: 
Connection refused")})
[root@node02 default.conf]# cqlsh ${IP}
connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'${IP}': 
ConnectionShutdown('Connection to ${IP} was closed',)})
```

It's not such obvious for me why 'Connection to ... was closed' is printed if connecting to rpc_address but 'Connectiong refused' when connecting to the localhost.
Does anyone know the cause of such problem?
cassandra.yaml file is bellow:

```
# Cassandra storage config YAML

cluster_name: '${NAME}'
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
authenticator: org.apache.cassandra.auth.AllowAllAuthenticator
data_file_directories:
    - /var/lib/cassandra/data
commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
hints_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/hints

key_cache_size_in_mb: 2    
key_cache_save_period: 14400    
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0    
row_cache_save_period: 0

saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches    
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000

concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32

storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001

rpc_port: 9042
start_rpc: true
rpc_keepalive: true    
rpc_server_type: sync

request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
index_interval: 128

listen_address: ${IP}
rpc_address: ${IP}
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: ${IP},${SEED}
```

Comment: Have you checked your firewall settings? Do a iptables -L and see that port 9042 is not blocked.

Comment: Another note not related to this issue. In the seeds configuration you should not use the own node as a seed (you can still set this node as seed for other nodes) unless it's the first node in the cluster. Seeds don't bootstrap, which means when you add new nodes in the cluster and set them as seeds they won't stream any data from other nodes. So your cassandra.yaml file should look like - seeds: ${SEED}

Comment: firewall is not installed yet at any servers in cassandra ring.
I've checked that port 9042 is listened by netstat.
tcp        0      0 176.241.109.36:9042     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      992        4923646    9208/java

Comment: Thank you, i've changed my ansible playbook so that self IP is not in seeds config. But cqlsh still not wokring

Comment: Can you try telnet the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. You set rpc_port to 9042. I think you're confusing rpc with native (cql). Rpc is the old interface that is deprecated in later releases. I would recommend setting start_rpc to false and set rpc_port back to it's default value: 9160.

Comment: It's fine) I've changed config but there is no process listening 9042. Tried both telnet and netstat. `nodetool status` output is the same as before

Comment: What's your configuration for native_transport_port ?

Comment: @ВіталійГонта Forgot to tag you

Comment: native_transport_port: 9042

Comment: Strange. Perhaps you can do a diff with the original configuration and upload the output to a site like pastebin. Must be some other configuration that is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for you help! There was a mistake in configuration file, already solved it